# Error deploying with mlGradle via load balancer

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We have a 3 node cluster setup in AWS fronted by a load balancer.  Accessing the admin UI, query console, and REST apis are fine through the load balancer.  But when deploying module content via mlGradle we get the following error.

```
:mlLoadModules FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlLoadModules'.
> Unable to insert content at URI: /config/context.xml; cause: Query evaluation request rejected (400, BAD_REQUEST). Is this an XDBC server?
```

This error is fine when going against a single node.  My guess is that it might be hitting different hosts, causing the failure.  I have the AWS load balancer setup for stickiness with cookies, but that does not seem to help.

Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was with the configuration of the AWS load balancer.  All of the endpoints are listed as HTTP endpoints, so I created the load balancer to proxy requests as HTTP.  In my specific deployment a file is loaded to the root of the module using XDBC.  The HTTP endpoints are also XDBC enabled, but the load balancer only accepted HTTP, which is why I was getting the bad request.  Switching the Load balancer to TCP for all the ports works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the basics: circumvent the load balancer, then hit each node separately in a controlled test. Make sure the rest is working like you expect per node. Then move onto the load balancer if each node looks OK on their own - sticky or not, it looks like you'r not hitting an XDBC server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is neither the load balancer nor Xdbc vs http.  xdbc is HTTP compatable, if it were not then no requests would work,   you can validate this by using. a 1 node cluster with the original configuration. It will work.  The ‘problem’,is a mis connect between the requirements of th administrative  operations being performed by mlgradle and the concept of load balencing.   Administrative operations which are sequenced may not work if they hit different ML servers for many reasons, one being timings and wait condition rest calls which are only valid in the server contacted,  ( eg, waiting for a host restart to complete, updating nodes in a particular order to accomidate failover,  transactions, session state, etc).

what you did to the load balancer  was to change it from cookie affinity to a different algorithm.  this does change behabiour but will not fundamentally fix it,  you also caused a ELB refresh which has been observed to cause the ELB to not load balencem for the first set of connections.   this causes false positive results on tests because no actual distribution of target servers occurs.   you can validate by starting a new ELB and testing back to back connections to see which servers are hit.   Note that MOST things generally work no matter what server is hit, you cannot validate “it works” simply by not noticing errors using black box testing — it can be difficult — or constant — to hit the exact sequence of events th% produce unexpected  (although not alwaysn wrong )behavior ...  you can see this in qconsole by using xdmp:host() .. run a few times, wait a while, repeat.   What do you expect ? did that occur ?  is it consistently reproduceable ? what kinds of applications behvious would be affected ? is it wrong ?If you don’t have the answers for this upfront, i recommend not using load balencers between application code and marklogic.  Instead use them between the applidation and internet/browser users if your application is fully stateless.  if not, then load balenders are not the solution.

Comment: Thanks @DALDEI. This was quite a while ago, and I think at that time there was also an issue with mlgradle not propagating the xcc.http-compliant flag.